# Menu dispareing when visititing current page

Tags: theme-development

I'm using the following code to produce a menu in a WordPress theme that I'm building. Each time I visit a page, that page's link within the menu is being removed.

```
<?php 
 /**
    * Displays a navigation menu
    * @param array $args Arguments
    */
    $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'menu' => '',
            'container' => '',
            'container_class' => '',
            'container_id' => '',
            'menu_class' => '',
            'menu_id' => '',
            'echo' => true,
            'fallback_cb' => 'custom_menu',
            'before' => '',
            'after' => '',
            'link_before' => '',
            'link_after' => '',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id = "nav" class = "">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth' => 0,
            'walker' => ''
    );

    wp_nav_menu( $args );
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have some CSS that is targeting and hiding one of the current menu item classes added by WordPress, such as `.current-menu-item` or `.current_page_item`. The code you've posted does not cause menu items to disappear as has been described.